# Contact information pulled from Facebook not being queried when selected

Tags: android, facebook, contacts

I have a button that lets a user choose a contact from their phone.

Using the basic info given from the android examples and a little digging I came up with this method

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        if (data != null)
        {
            Uri contactData = data.getData();
            if (contactData != null)
            {
                Cursor c = null;
                try
                {
                    c = getContentResolver().query(contactData, null, null, null, null);
                    if (c != null && c.moveToFirst())
                    {
                        String name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
                        String phone = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

                        mEditTextName.setText(name);
                        mEditTextPhone.setText(phone);
                    }
                } finally
                {
                    if (c != null)
                    {
                        c.close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The issue is when a contact has been imported from Facebook, the cursor has no rows.

Does anyone know how to over come this, and get the person's name and phone number?